# do I need to login the second time I use "paypal standard payment"?

Tags: paypal

Paypal Payment Standard doesn't require to be registered to paypal to perform payment.

However I've read on a blog that the second time you proceed, it recognize your credit card and ask you to register to paypal.

Could you give me a 100% sure answer about this ? I really cannot ask customers to create paypal accounts.

thanks

**Update**:
I've found the following extract on a website:

> Are PayPal accounts required in order
>   to make a purchase or donation? Not
>   any more. It was this way before but
>   PayPal.com changed the policy. You may
>   make ONE non-recurring transaction
>   without opening a PayPal account
>   however, PayPal creates a temporary
>   PayPal account with credit card number
>   used. If you use the same credit card
>   again with so many months, PayPal will
>   ask to open and verify an account.

I was wondering **how often** it should be a payment done to see paypal asking to make an account. For example, let's say that I'm performing the second payment after 2 weeks. Is it going to ask me for a paypal account ?

thanks

Comment: Two such unrelated questions should be raised separately!

Comment: done, I've created another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Google Checkout? Like PayPal Payment Standard it does not require a monthly fee.

[Google](https://checkout.google.com/sell/?gl=IS&hl=en) :

> When you use Google Checkout to process your sales, you'll be charged rates as low as 1.9% + $0.30 per transaction, depending on your monthly sales volume. And there are no monthly, setup or gateway fees.

Although, I do think it makes you have an account, but so many people have a Google account anyway ...

Comment: I live in Europe, I've just found out Google Checkout is not available yet here. Paypal is perfect, if it doesn't ask my customer to login... I need to understand well how much time the credit card is temporarily stored after the first payment.